# How to start a service in background and from that service how to start an Activity?

Tags: android-service

I want to start a service in background. I won't launch this service from any broadcast receiver or activity. Is it possible anyway to start a service in background without any receiver or activity intervention? And from that service how to start an activity?

Please help me with a suitable example and explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to start either a `Service` or an `Activity` is the application's `Context`. That's where you can call `startService()`, `startActivity`, `startActivityForResult()`, etc. There first time you can have the `Context` object available inside your app is in `onCreate()` of your main activity (as defined in *AndroidManifest.xml*).